# How to lock document files?

Tags: java, linux, window

Is there any way to lock files of these types:

1. txt
2. pdf
3. docx
4. doc

If locked, it should not be possible to edit, copy or print it.

Comment: And another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045734/java-file-locking

Comment: This site has [search functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/search). Use it before posting a new question.

Comment: @Gary Don't be misled by the use of “lock” in the question.  This is not about locking a file, it's about locking down the content.  It is not a duplicate of either of those questions.

Comment: @VGR Yes thats what i needed.